# Routing preventing controller from working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I’m developing a web application using AngularJS. I have a little problem. The view (html) can’t find the controller (js).  So, I think this is caused by the routing in my app.js. The link to all the code can be found below. The pages are not loading well on plunker. So, I attached the images to this post.
[image: The login page]
[image: The select page and the errors]
Also, the code posted below is the index.html. http://plnkr.co/edit/CIQSZ0pow1Z9Pfsre1xO?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<link href="app-content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--<link href="css/generation-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<link href="css/image-collection-generation.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="css/image-header.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/mix-collections.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
<link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/view-collections.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/view-selected-collection.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div ng-view>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
</script>-->
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-cookies.js">
</script>
<script src="app.js">
</script>
<script src="app-services/authentication.service.js">
</script>
<script src="app-services/flash.service.js">
</script>
<!-- Real user service that uses an api -->
<!-- <script src="app-services/user.service.js">
</script> -->
<!-- Fake user service for demo that uses local storage -->
<script src="app-services/user.service.local-storage.js">
</script>
<script src="home.controller.js">
</script>
<script src="login.controller.js">
</script>
<script src="register.controller.js">
</script>
<!-- <script src="select/select.controller.js">
</script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got HomeController
angular.js:9997

So to sum it up, when the app routes to the select page, the angular controller is not recognized by the select page and I cannot add any functionalities. It is important to mention that the select page does work (and so does the controller) as a stand-alone page, but once I link the login page through ngRoute, the problem occurs.

Comment: The plnkr code you uploaded is not even loading, would you add the missing .css files?

Comment: @Leibniz, some parts of the code is proprietary. Could you please look at the code and check where the probable bug is? Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of problems with this - I'm not even sure where to begin. You can't put your `<script>` tags that reference your Angular modules on the view templates. For your `/select` route you define `templateUrl: select.html`, but it looks like it should be `select.view.html`. You have `ng-controller` in your view, but when using ngRoute the controller is defined and injected into the view with the `$routeProvider.when()` which you have done specifying `controller: SelectController` and `controllerAs: vm` so you should be using that on your view.